# PHP, Site multilanguage. Best practice

Tags: php, localization, multilingual

I have one not resolved question about localization on ANY site. When we create site (we - means developers) we use simple functions to change text for localization and it works fine for text or some sentences. And what about landing pages where text is huge part of page content. Let me exaplain on Yii2 example.

When we use

```
\Yii::t('', 'apply');
```

or

```
\Yii::t('', 'No avatar was uploaded yet.');
```

it's fine(I think), but when we use such thing

```
\Yii::t('', 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.');
```

I don't it's great idead. So I'm searching for best practice of translation of HUGE text (not for site interface).

Comment: What do you expect? A computer speaking all natural languages, and thus translating them sensible? Not yet. :-) Maybe in a few years.

Comment: What about gettext, or, more advanced - intl? http://mel.melaxis.com/devblog/2005/08/06/localizing-php-web-sites-using-gettext/ and http://de2.php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php